# Почему в php storm все файлы изменены при работе с git?

Tags: git, phpstorm

Ситуация такая, склонировал репозиторий и создал новую ветку. Поработав в этой ветке немного, я заметил, что php storm подсвечивает все файлы синим цветом, как-будто они изменены. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: 1. в переводах строк.  

2. в том, что сам шторм их чуточку поменял. git diff все расскажет

Comment: diff --git a/.gitignore b/.gitignore
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
diff --git a/admin/controller/catalog/attribute.php b/admin/controller/catalog/attribute.php
old mode 100644
new mode 100755

Что бы это могло значить?

Comment: @KoVadim, как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждый раз, когда гит извлекает файлы, он им назначает права  644 или 755 (первое - читать/писать пользователю, остальным только читать. второе - плюс право на исполнение всем). По какой то причине гит решил, что файлы исполняемые и добавил им этот флажок. Может это среда накосячила, может из за того, что маски плохо настроены. Если Вас это мало волнует, отключите гиту необходимость отслеживать такое

```
git config core.filemode false
```

Или для всех на своей машине

```
git config --global core.filemode false
```

Comment: да, но что мне сделать, чтобы не коммитить теперь весь проект, а только те файлы, которые я реально изменил?

Comment: после приведенной выше команды, все "неверно помеченные как измененные" файлы должны стать "не измененными" и проблем с коммитом не должно возникнуть. Если это не так, я бы рекомендовал для начала посмотреть в консоли их статус. И если он "неверный", то поправить ручками - `chmod 644 *` (или явно указать имена). Также можно попробовать прямо в идее выделить нужные файлы и откатить.